# Why API throws Error 500 on hosting but works locally?

Tags: c#, api, fetch-api

I've just developed a very simple API just to test some things.

It works fine localhost, even connecting to my online database, but on the production environment it throws error 500.

Can anyone point me to a direction to why does this happen?

I'll add part of the code below:

```
const uri = '/api/depoimentos';
function getItems() {
    fetch(uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => _displayItems(data))
        .catch(error => console.error('Unable to get items.', error));
```

It throws error on this catch, but only says "Error 500".

```
    [Route("api/depoimentos")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepoimentosController : ControllerBase
    {
        ...

        // GET: api/Depoimentos
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<DepoimentoDTO>>> GetDepoimentos()
        {
            if (_context.Depoimentos == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return await _context.Depoimentos
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(x => x.Arquivo)
                .Select(x => ItemToDTO(x))
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        ...
```

Postman showing error 500 on hosted application
[image: Postman showing error 500 on hosted application]

Localhost working accessing hosted database (please ignore the ugly test interface XD)
[image]

Postman working localhost
[image]

Comment: Most probably you should change your deployment options. Post here what deployment options did you use.

Comment: @Rafael Here are the publish settings of the project: [link](https://postimg.cc/4KDrgsd7) . I'm publishing it in an Windows environment from a small local hosting company where I have other web apps (.NET Core apps) and they all work fine.

Comment: Just for experimental purposes, try to publish the project as `win-x86` instead of `win-x64`.

Comment: Also I recommend to use "Debug - Attach to process" and attach debugger to the process running on the host, that you used as a publishing target. When error occurred, debugger will display the line where did it happen and error message.

Comment: If you have access to the host's event log you can check it for details on the error.

Comment: @Rafael it....worked....but how? or why? Every other application I have hosted there uses win-x64 as target runtime. Thank you very very much!

Comment: To find the real reason add Application Insights to your project and check the logs. There you find the whole exception info including the stack trace. Already helped me multiple times to find such awkward errors.